# How to separate SSE from AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, server-sent-events

when I use SSE (Server-Side Events) and ajax queries, I get ajax response only with the response of the event on the server. Is it possible to receive ajax responses regardless of SSE events?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem on the site:

https://developer.hyvor.com/php/ajax-long-polling

specifically, it is:

Session data can't be used in long polling. If you do, it will completely freeze the browser tab. Other requests sent to the same domain won't load. Adding session_write_close() function at the top of the script can cancel the usage of sessions in the script.